# How to "mute" ls command?

Tags: ls

Suppose I do a recursive `ls`

```
$ ls -R
```

on the root directory.

I get a lot of messages like these -

```
ls: cannot open directory ./var/lib/sendmail: Permission denied
ls: cannot open directory ./var/lib/sudo: Permission denied
...
```

Is there a way to avoid displaying the above "`cannot open directory`" messages?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since these are error messages, they are sent to stderr not stdout. The solution is that you redirect stderr:

```
ls -R 2>/dev/null
```

**Explanation:**

Any command has 3 standard file descriptors: standard input (0) (usually the terminal where you type in commands), standard output (1) (usually the terminal where the command prints its output) standard error (2) (by default it's the same as standard output).

Most (if not all) programs/tools print warnings and errors to the standard error file descriptor. Now the file descriptors wouldn't be much use if they were fixed; which is why the shell offers *redirection*: you can redirect any of the standard file descriptors to any file you want.

Redirecting stdin (to take input from a file instead of from your keyboard):

```
interactive_program 0< file_with_answers
```

As you can see this can help you automate the running of simple programs that ask a lot of questions by providing a so-called "answer file" served on standard input.

This can be shortened to

```
 interactive_program < file_with_answers
```

as the `<` makes the redirection clear (*from* the file *to* the program)

Similarly, stdout can be redirected via `1>...` or `>...` or `>>...` (append to an existing file instead of truncating it)

Standard error redirection requires that you specify the file descriptor explicitly like so: `2>...`, so what the above does is it directs all errors to the special file `/dev/null` which is sort of a black hole for bits.

[Relevant reading](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) on redirection as provided by MattDMo in the comments below.

Comment: what is 2>  ? Can you please explain?

Comment: It's a redirection command. `>` will redirect `stdout` or standard output, `2>` redirects `stderr` or standard error. `1>` is the same as `>`, so you can see where the `2` comes from. You can read more about I/O redirection [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) on the Linux Documentation Project.

Comment: @CodeBlue See my updated answer.